# Drupal and security hardening - PHP chmod

Tags: security

I am struggling with the following case with Drupal and PHP hardening on an Red Hat Linux infrastructure.

For drupal installation a user has been created. All the files and directories are owned by this specific user. Due to the security hardening that we have applied, we restricted `chmod` from PHP and now drupal is not working properly. In order for new content to be uploaded to site from the Administrative panel, chmod is being used so that files should be uploaded under `/sites/default/files` with the proper rights.

Also I have problem when updating the Drupal CMS as .css files are also not uploaded with the correct permissions. 600 **instead of** 644.

Could I somehow make drupal work correctly with restricting chmod?

Is chmod a requirement in order for Drupal to work?

I have included apache user in the user (the owner of drupal files) group but still cannot make it work with restricted chmod. If I remove chmod restriction then Drupal works properly.

Chmod is restricted through `disable_functions` of `php.ini`

Can you advise?

Comment: All Drupal should be owned by `some_user:www-data`. What's your group?

Comment: Drupal is owned currently from the user that made the installation (x user). Should I change all drupal directory recursively to `apache:apache` as I am in a red Hat installation? Could it then work with restricted chmod?

Comment: The drupal directory is owned by `x:x` where x is the user and the same for the group.